# Draw in wx.PaintDC

Tags: wxpython

I am trying to create a canvas and draw on it based on the position of the mouse cursor.
Example:

```
class Lienzo:
  def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()

    self.app2 = wx.App()
    self.ventana2 = wx.Frame(None,id= wx.ID_ANY,title= "Area de dibujo",size= (800,600))
    self.icono = wx.Icon("imagenes/logo.png")
    self.ventana2.SetIcon(self.icono)
    self.panel2 = wx.Panel(self.ventana2,pos= (0,0),size= (800,600))

    self.contLienzo = wx.Panel(self.panel2,pos= (20,100),size= (500,400), style=wx.BORDER_SIMPLE)
    self.contLienzo.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.pressMouse)
    self.contLienzo.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.releaseMouse)
    self.contLienzo.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.dibujar)
    
    self.ventana2.Show()
    self.app2.MainLoop()

  def pressMouse(self,event):
    self.pos1 = event.GetPosition()

  def releaseMouse(self,event):
    self.pos2 = event.GetPosition()

  def dibujar(self,event3):
    self.lienzo = wx.PaintDC(self.contLienzo)
    self.lapiz = wx.Pen("black",width=1,style= wx.PENSTYLE_SOLID)
    self.lienzo.SetPen(self.lapiz)         
    self.lienzo.DrawLine(self.pos1.x,self.pos1.y,self.pos2.x,self.pos2.y) 

obj = Lienzo()
```

I tried to use wx.PaintDC's DrawLine function in the releaseMouse() function but it didn't work either.
How can I get the cursor position when pressing and releasing the mouse button?

Answer (score 0):

wxPython only invokes the OnPaint method when the frame is painted (on first drawing, resizing or Refresh) ([See the docs](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.PaintEvent.html#wx-paintevent))

So you must override the OnPaint method with your code and make sure to call the Refresh method when you want to invoke painting; in this case in releaseMouse

```
import wx

class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(None, *args, **kwargs)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

        self.pos1, self.pos2 = None, None
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.pressMouse)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.releaseMouse)

    def pressMouse(self, event):
        self.pos1 = event.GetPosition()

    def releaseMouse(self, event):
        self.pos2 = event.GetPosition()
        self.Refresh()

    def OnPaint(self, event=None):
        if self.pos1:
            dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
            dc.Clear()
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(wx.RED, 4))
            dc.DrawLine(self.pos1[0], self.pos1[1], self.pos2[0], self.pos2[1])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wx_app = wx.App()
    MainFrame()
    wx_app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: If it's the answer, please mark it as answered